# Does the hudna (هدنة) has a base in the religion or it is a secular term?

Tags: terminology, religion, treaty

Does the hudna (هدنة) has a base in the religion or it is a secular term?

I have searched for it on google and got the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hudna) information which is not informative enough to what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

هدنة is an Islamic term that is used extensively in Islamic literature.

> الهدنة، أن يعقد لأهل الحرب عقدا على ترك القتال مدة، بعوض وبغير عوض. وتسمى مهادنة وموادعة ومعاهدة
>
> هدنة is a contract with the ahl al-harb to cease fighting for a limited period of time, with tribute or without tribute. And it is also called مهادنة   and موادعة  and معاهدة
>
> <sup>— [Mughni](https://shamela.ws/index.php/book/8463/4210#p6) -  Ibn Qudamah</sup>

The basis for such a treaty exists in the Quran such as:

> إلا الذين عاهدتم من المشركين ثم لم ينقصوكم شيئا ولم يظاهروا عليكم أحدا فأتموا إليهم عهدهم إلى مدتهم
>
> Excepted are those with whom you made a treaty among the polytheists and then they have not been deficient toward you in anything or supported anyone against you; so complete for them their treaty until their term [has ended].
>
> <sup>— [Quran 9:4](https://quran.com/9/4?translations=20)</sup>

And the Sunnah, such as:

> صالح النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم المشركين يوم الحديبية
>
> On the day of Hudaibiya, the Prophet (ﷺ), the Prophet (ﷺ) made a peace treaty with the Al-Mushrikun
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:2700)</sup>
>
> أنهم اصطلحوا على وضع الحرب عشر سنين
>
> ... They agreed to abandon war for ten years ...
>
> <sup>— [Abu Dawud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:2766)</sup>

> ثم **هدنة** تكون بينكم وبين بني الأصفر فيغدرون
>
> A truce between you and Bani Al-Asfar (i.e. the Byzantines) who will betray you
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3176)</sup>

Making such a treaty is permissible when the Muslims are weak or when there is an interest served by it.

Comment: Thanks. From your things, I am not sure if it is a term referring to such agreement between Muslims to Muslims or between Muslims to non-Muslims, or both.   Kindly, clear this point.

Comment: It is between the Muslims and non-Muslims.